# Update specific value of one file by values in another text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line, replace

I have a text files in ascii format and wanted to replace a specific value by value saved in another text file.

consider a file of name `text_1. . . . 50.asc` 5 columns, 4 rows

sample data in a file

```
 0.40007 0.544 0.6795 0.1545 -3.4028
 0.61488 0.8471 0.7444 0.3537 0.0709
 0.65128 0.6651 0.7948 0.9200 0.893
 0.70952 0.5990 0.5061 0.610 0.893
```

And I wanted to replace (5th column, 1st row) of each file by value same in `Replacing_values.txt`.

It have data

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
50
```

Expected result (continued to all files)

```
 0.40007 0.544 0.6795 0.1545  1
 0.61488 0.8471 0.7444 0.3537 0.0709
 0.65128 0.6651 0.7948 0.9200 0.893
 0.70952 0.5990 0.5061 0.610 0.893
```

I have tried this

```
for i in `seq 50`; do x=`awk 'FNR==(1) {print $5}' *.asc`; y=`cat Replacing_values.txt`; echo $x==$y ;done
```

Comment: *4th column, 1st row* - you meant **5**th column? Why comparing values `echo $x==$y` ?

Comment: Yes 5th column, sorry I didn't know how to do it, just randomly doing it. I am new in it. If you can help in this regard. I'll be thankful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flexible GNU **`awk`** features:

```
gawk -i inplace -v repl="Replacing_values.txt" 'FNR==1{ getline $5 < repl }1' *.asc
```

- `-i inplace` - allows to modify the input file(s) in-place
- `-v repl="Replacing_values.txt"` - a variable keeping the filename with replace values
- `FNR==1` - consider only the 1st line of each input file
- `getline $5 < repl` - read next record from `repl` file and assign it to the 5th column `$5`

Comment: It worked well, Thank you so much, Sir.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, you're welcome!

Comment: ... note that the order in which the shell expands `*.asc` will not necessarily correspond to the order of lines in `Replacing_values.txt` - you might want to use brace expansion `text_{1..50}.asc` instead

Comment: @steeldriver, that's a good reminder